# Change Twenty twelve theme background color

Tags: css, theme-twenty-twelve

I use the twenty twelve theme and I would like to change the background color manually by modifying the right files in the `plugins` folder. However, I can not find what to change in the style.css file. I even tried to modify the background color through the Wordpress interface to #e50000. After that, I looked for a line containing e50000 in my wordpress directory, but there seems to be none.

I can't figure out which line to change in my wordpress directory to change the background color.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The background is a option. You can set colors and also images. See in the Administration area, Appearance --> Background

[image]

[image]

Also you can use the Live Preview link on the theme and customize the background and other otpions.
[image]

Comment: Sorry if I was not clear in my question. I wanted to manually change the background color of the theme by modifying the right files in the plugins folder. I edited the question.

Comment: The values was not in the theme folder, was set via option and add to the head in frontend. If you will change this without the default option, then set a `background-color` to the `body` tag, like: `body { background-color: #e50000 !important; }`.

Comment: thank you! I didn't know about `!important` in css!

Answer (score 0):

Changing the theme background color can be done with the build in theme customizer. 
Go to `themes`->`customize`. On the left you will see the customize options.
In the colors tab you will find the background color.

No need to code this ;)

Comment: This looks like a poor duplicate of @bueltge's answer

Comment: I think he was at the same moment as my answer ;)

Comment: I was first ;) but his is a better answer obviously.

Answer (score 0):

When you change the background color through the dashboard (as mentioned by @bueltge), it is `echo`'d directly into the site head using `<style>` tags. You can override the background color in your `style.css` by setting it on the `body` element:

```
body {
    background-color: #efefef !important;
}
```

The `!important` part ensures that the color specified in `style.css` overrides the one set in the dashboard.

Comment: Might be stupid, but can I ask you how you set the background color to none in the dashboard? If you mean deleting the color number entirely, it doesn't seem to be right, because a strange light blue color is then displayed in the background.

Comment: See updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Easy. In the twentytwelve theme, search for this:

```
.site {
    padding: 0 24px;
    padding: 0 1.714285714rem;
    background-color: #888;
}
```

And change the `background-color` to what you'd like it to be.